Gravity Forms Show number field in notifcation email when hidden by custom logic
I have a number field ID:60. I have it conditional visible and defaulted to 0. I want it to display in the notification email. It only populates when I have it visible. How do I make it populate when not visible?
Dear {Name (First):51.3} {Name (Last):51.6},

Thank you for you interest in our services. Your estimated total cost is ${Estimate:60}.


The issue is that the field is not populating with the default value when it is conditionally hidden.  If it set permanently to hidden, it will utilize the default.
